# Is ArrayList supported in Apache Axis Web service?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, arraylist, tomcat6

I have written a simple HelloWorld web service. Which takes an ArrayList as parameter. Code is as simple as `import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Service {

public void service(ArrayList<Object> list) {
    System.out.println("Hello World..");
}
}`
```

I am using Eclipse Helios SR1 and trying to geneate the Web service. 
Selecting Webservice Implementation to "Service" and Selecting Server runtime as Tomcat 6.0 and webservice runtime as Apache Axis. Clicking on next gives warning as 
The service class `"Service"` does not comply to one or more requirements of the `JAX-RPC 1.1` specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
  The method "service" on the service class `"Service"` uses a data type, `"java.util.ArrayList"`, that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.

Clicking ok to continue and it shows more warning one by one : 
The input type java.lang.Class is a non-instantiable type and will be omitted from the sample JSP.  Continue with sample JSP generation?

The input type javax.xml.namespace.QName is a non-instantiable type and will be omitted from the sample JSP.  Continue with sample JSP generation?

IWAB0189W The Sample JSP client omitted some methods because they contained unsupported types.

Any reason why it may be happening?
I saw on Sun site : [Sun RPC Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC2.html)

According to it ArrayList should be supported.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `List` instead of `ArrayList`?

Comment: With List also I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quoted from the specification.

> Arrays
>
> JAX-RPC also supports arrays with members of supported JAX-RPC types.
>   Examples of supported arrays are int[] and String[]. Multidimensional
>   arrays, such as BigDecimal[][], are also supported.

A simple modification of your method signature to accept an array as opposed to an ArrayList should fix the problem.

Comment: Well is ArrayList not supported?

Comment: How can ArrayList be supported? Think about non-Java apps consuming your SOAP services. JAX-RPC might be able to map a List to an array type, you should use the interface anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's really good practice to write the WSDL and then generate java classes using Axis WSDL2Java tool. You can always concentrate more on writing WSDL as per your business needs and leave all the hassle of marshaling and unmarshaling to generate classes.

Comment: So Suken, If we can write own WSDL then we can support ArrayList<Object> ? Actually my webService takes a VO which has an ArrayList<Serializable> can that be also supported ?

Comment: Sorry mate for delayed response (Friday night + lazy saturday). Yes if you are using JAX-RPC as service provider for your web service and your server and clients are written in java then you can serialize the Java object containing arraylist as they will be for sure entertained at both the ends. Your VO then needs to be serialized and deserialized using BeanSerializer. NOTE : Please remember this will only support java based application.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not getting how to write the WSDL? Can you suggest how to write wsdl ? for Service? Which takes a VO and VO has String and Map as parameters? (I need to support only java types)